# VB6 ADO INSERT of TEXT field into .MDB

Tags: ms-access, vb6, odbc, ado

My example VB6 program:

```
Dim conn As New connection
conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=" & App.Path & "\adatabase.mdb;"
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO atable (afield) VALUES (""some text"")"
End Sub
```

("adatabase.mdb" contains one table "atable" with one field "afield" of type "Text" length 255.  Access 2002, Access file format 2000.  VB6 references include "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library".)

conn.Execute gets:

> Runtime error '-2147217904 (80040e10' [Microsoft][ODBC Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

The query

```
INSERT INTO atable (afield) VALUES ("some text")
```

runs directly in Access without any problem.

Comment: You're still writing VB6?! "[The final release was version 6 in 1998. Microsoft's extended support ended in March 2008 and the designated successor was Visual Basic .NET (now known simply as Visual Basic).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)"

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. Not news. Naturally I have reasons which I won't go into here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO atable (afield) VALUES ("""some text""")"
```

i.e. you need to quote the double quotes?

Update: or as the poster solved, use single quotes to quote text.

Or even better, use a parameterised query:

```
Dim Conn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Dim Param1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Rs1 As ADODB.Recordset

' Create and Open Connection Object.
Set Conn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Conn1.ConnectionString = "DSN=Biblio;UID=admin;PWD=;"
Conn1.Open

' Create Command Object.
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1
Cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Authors WHERE AU_ID < ?"

' Create Parameter Object.
Set Param1 = Cmd1.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, 5)
Param1.Value = 5
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Param1
Set Param1 = Nothing

' Open Recordset Object.
Set Rs1 = Cmd1.Execute()
```

Comment: Actually that line is not syntactic but it did remind me that I could use single-quotes around my text instead of doubles and that solves the problem... for now... until I have to escape single-quotes but I'm sure there's help for that somewhere already!

Thanks Mitch!

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to use a parameterised query.